# cakephp 3.0 submit part of form

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

is there way to submit part of a form without refreshing the whole page? Basically, I want to add a search box with a button in the view, when I click this button it runs a function / action in the controller. My apology if this has been asked before but I've searched for couple of hours and I couldn't understand the ones I came across.

Comment: Try to use Jquery Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This page will help you learn about how CakePHP handles AJAX:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html
Now, be aware the default behavior of a form is submit itself to a page or to the same page (reloads). If you want to prevent the form from submitting (reload the page) have something like this:

```
<form onsubmit = myFunc() >
..

function myFunc(){

//Send the ajax request. You can use JQuery

//Handle response

return false; //This will prevent the page reload...

}
```